# Spring MVC with Spring Security a simple example does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having trouble with setting up a simple spring security. I'm trying to set up the most simple example possible with the configuration below. It seems that the request never gets intercepted?

**Project structure**

[image]

**BasicController.java**

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class BasicController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring/context.xml
      /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter>

</web-app>
```

**security.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:http-basic />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

**context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

    <bean id="templateLoader" class="de.neuland.jade4j.spring.template.SpringTemplateLoader">
        <property name="basePath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jadeConfiguration" class="de.neuland.jade4j.JadeConfiguration">
        <property name="prettyPrint" value="false" />
        <property name="caching" value="false" />
        <property name="templateLoader" ref="templateLoader" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="de.neuland.jade4j.spring.view.JadeViewResolver">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jadeConfiguration" />
        <property name="renderExceptions" value="true" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Logs**

It evident that both spring configuration files are being read and security is mapped onto `Creating access control expression attribute 'isAuthenticated()' for /**` and yet the page is not protected!

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 63383
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63383', transport: 'socket'
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:42 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:42 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 25 11:50:42 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:42 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/context.xml]
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:43 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security.xml]
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:43 AM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFO: You are running with Spring Security Core 4.2.0.RELEASE
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:43 AM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.2.0.RELEASE
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:43 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap
INFO: Creating access control expression attribute 'isAuthenticated()' for /**
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:43 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthenticationConfigBuilder createLoginPageFilterIfNeeded
INFO: No login page configured. The default internal one will be used. Use the 'login-page' attribute to set the URL of the login page.
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:43 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFO: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 800, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpConfigurationBuilder$SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterBeanFactory#0; factoryMethodName=getBean; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2300, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2400]
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:44 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:45 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/hello],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String controller.BasicController.hello()
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:45 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 25 11:50:42 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:45 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 25 11:50:42 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:46 AM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFO: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4a5905d9, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1a3e5f23, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6293e39e, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@365553de, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@34a0ef00, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5c0f79f0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@21fdfefc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3daa82be, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@ec1b2e4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@29a69a35, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@67e28be3, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@e344ad3, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@de18f63, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@108bdbd8]
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4797 ms
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:47 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'web': initialization started
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'web-servlet': startup date [Fri Nov 25 11:50:47 GMT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Nov 25, 2016 11:50:47 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'web': initialization completed in 25 ms
```

I preferably want to use XML configuration rather than java. However, if I try to use an annotation `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize` I will get an exception `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException` when I try to access the page:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:976)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:856)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at controller.BasicController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf19eb0f.hello(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:964)
```

Comment: Given that the expression is `/**` every page should be protected. In the controller there is only one http://{host}:{port}/hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally used IntelliJ with Jetty plugin which does not work.

I was able to successfully run the Spring security on **Tomcat server**.

Answer (score 0):

For the context part, i noticed that you forgot to specify the path to the actual file (spring config file):
`<init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>`
You simply have to replace that part to the new one :

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: That is true but it is being loaded via `ContextLoaderListener`.